# Is it time to lose [gain]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) tag only has 23 questions, 8 of which were asked this year.
It is not very specific, and most of it's [tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) cover a pretty broad array of issues.

The most common usage of the tag has to do with audio gain. These questions are fine, but is [gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) really the right tag to use for these? Most of them are already tagged with [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio).

At the very least, I think this tag could use some cleanup, and probably a wiki, as it doesn't currently have one.

Comment: Should do [loss] too

Comment: If the title was *lose weight [gain] immediately*, it would have been funnier (and the spam scripts would have caught your question) :D

Comment: If we wanted to include [tag:weight], you could really write a good pun title for this like "Do we still have to endure [weight] [loss] and [gain] this year?"

Comment: Or what @BhargavRao said

Comment: Wow you guys are a lot punnier than I am.. Are multiple tag burninate-requests allowed?

Comment: "Are multiple tag burninate-requests allowed?" Hey, whatever it takes to m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶t̶y̶ ̶t̶i̶t̶l̶e̶ clean up the site. Or something like that.

Comment: ["DO NOT try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751) - from the burnination guidelines.

Comment: @TinyGiant: For what it's worth, well-received burninate requests routinely violate that guideline, although always with *thematically related* tags, where the decision to be made is usually which (if any) can be saved and which need to be edited toward those or other tags.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: While I agree with the sentiment, as far as giving advice goes we should be in-line with the guidelines available to us, otherwise what is the point of having guidelines in the first place.

Comment: @TinyGiant... revising them when they prove to be unhelpful or overly cautious? The guidelines we have are *pragmatic*; they're not there because they've been formally proven to be the only semantically sound way to approach things, but simply happen to usually get the right results when applied with sound judgement. They were not given to us by angels descending from on high.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Don't get me wrong, I do agree, but this is coming from the position of giving advice on the topic, not from the position of discussing whether or not the guidelines are correct. That would be a separate topic all on it's own. I don't believe that the guidelines were given to us from on high, but I do believe that in practice we should follow the current guidelines. If we want to change those guidelines, then we should have a dedicated discussion about that.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Ehh, sometimes it's best to try things out first and ask forgiveness later, but I do see what you mean. I left a comment there, in any case.

Comment: I personally see the three terms related enough to be treated as a single entity. Sort of head and tails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and purged the remains of [gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) off StackOverflow. Here is a list of re-tagged questions and actions taken for posterity and community scrutiny:

**Retagged Questions:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206231/control-gain-of-a-externally-connected-usb-mic-in-android -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [Oculus Rift SDK 2 changing the rotational gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233617/oculus-rift-sdk-2-changing-the-rotational-gain) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [Android AudioRecord disable gain filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456509/android-audiorecord-disable-gain-filter) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [Programmatically turn off VoiceProcessingIO AGC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644871/programmatically-turn-off-voiceprocessingio-agc) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [Strange gain change after initializing kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922513/strange-gain-change-after-initializing-kaudiounitsubtype-voiceprocessingio) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [Standalone AGC (auto gain control) in WebRtc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334937/standalone-agc-auto-gain-control-in-webrtc-application) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) -[auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [AudioRecord with Gain Adjustment not working on Samsung Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291942/audiorecord-with-gain-adjustment-not-working-on-samsung-device) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) +[audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)

**Tag removed without replacement:**

- [How to increase the microphone gain while recording?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366841/how-to-increase-the-microphone-gain-while-recording) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)
- [Smooth Volume Change in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302170/smooth-volume-change-in-java) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) -[clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clicking)
- [How Do I Calculate Audio Gain using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988408/how-do-i-calculate-audio-gain-using-c) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)
- [Avoid overmodulation/distorsion when applying gain to PCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357621/avoid-overmodulation-distorsion-when-applying-gain-to-pcm) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)
- [How can I manually change the gain level of an Android AudioTrack stream using a scalar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844695/how-can-i-manually-change-the-gain-level-of-an-android-audiotrack-stream-using-a) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)
- [searching presence of words in different lines in a set of lines. c# windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596450/searching-presence-of-words-in-different-lines-in-a-set-of-lines-c-sharp-window) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain) -[info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info)
- [Flex4 - Microphone gain vs OS microphone input volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787580/flex4-microphone-gain-vs-os-microphone-input-volume) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)
- [How to vary gain value of gain block in Simulink during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460329/how-to-vary-gain-value-of-gain-block-in-simulink-during-runtime) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)
- [Web audio API polyphony - using 2 different gain nodes not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252396/web-audio-api-polyphony-using-2-different-gain-nodes-not-working) -[gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gain)